# Vb.Net waiting for process 30secs

Tags: vb.net

I have three events to fire on button click.

after running the first event i want to wait for 30sec to wait for nex event to fire.

how i can wait( i mean looping for 30 secs).

Thanks,
Nag

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx

Answer (score 7):

You can try this to your code directly:

```
    MessageBox.Show("Test") ' Execute your method 1
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(30000)
    MessageBox.Show("Test2") ' Proceed with the other one :)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you wait on the UI thread you'll block the whole UI and Windows will show your application as non-responding.

Better to:

- Update the UI to show it is busy, including disabling controls to block user input.
- Use a timer control (details depend on WinForms or WPF) to trigger an event after the time delay
- Do the work in the timer's event handler.

If the work is CPU or IO intensive (ie. likely to block for more than a few tens of milliseconds) then perform the work in the threadpool (eg. [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) component). Remember you'll need to use Control.Invoke to make any changes to the UI from the worker thread.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Thread `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(30000);` to hold execution.

Answer (score 0):

use a timer for it and set an interval of 30 seconds to timer `(1sec = 1000)`

```
timer1.Interval=30000
```